# How to incorporate score margins into the Weng-Lin ranking models?

Tags: ranking, bradley-terry-model

I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate this formula from [this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/s13428-021-01714-2.pdf) into the [Weng-Lin](https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume12/weng11a/weng11a.pdf) update rule algorithms:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{P}[i \text{ beats } j] &= \frac{\exp{\lambda_i}}{\exp{\lambda_i} + \exp{\lambda_j}} \\
\lambda_i &= \sum_k^N X_{i,k} \beta_k \\
y_i &\sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(\mathcal{P}[i \text{ beats } j])
\end{align}

Priors:

$$\beta_k \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_\beta^2)$$

The chief assumption here being that score margins are player specific predictors. Then given that from equation (57) of Weng's paper:

$$
\lambda_i = \frac{\mu_i}{c_{iq}}
$$

Since $\lambda_i$ has different values, how do I merge these two concepts? If it's impossible to add a score margin with this method, what other method can be used?